# Standard library facilities which allocate but don't use an Allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, std, allocator

In most places where the C++ standard library allocates memory, the user is able to customise this by providing a class which meets the [`Allocator` requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator). For example, almost all containers take an allocator template argument, and `std::allocate_shared` returns a `shared_ptr` whose contained element and control block are both allocated via a provided Allocator.

However, there are a few places where the standard library can (potentially) allocate memory, but no `Allocator` support is provided. The ones I can think of are:

- `std::make_unique()` (no corresponding `allocate_unique()`)
- `std::any`
- `std::function` (allocator support will be removed in C++17)
- `std::valarray`
- `std::basic_filebuf` (although `std::basic_stringbuf` *does* use an Allocator)
- `std::inplace_merge()`

**Questions:**

- I'm sure this list is incomplete, but what else have I missed?
- Of the non-Allocator classes and functions, are they specified to use global `::operator new`, plain `new`, or is the memory source unspecified?
- If anybody knows, what are the reasons for not providing allocator support in `any`, and removing it from `function`?

Comment: This is going to be one long list...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not an exhaustive list.

- Everything in `<stdexcept>`, which needs to allocate memory to store the message string.
- The standard pool/monotonic memory resource classes obviously allocate memory, but they do it from another memory resource, not an allocator, so they technically fit your description.
- `boyer_moore_searcher` and `boyer_moore_horspool_searcher`.
- Several `<algorithm>` algorithms attempt to obtain additional memory (e.g., `stable_partition`, `stable_sort`) and all parallel algorithms (regardless of header) may need additional memory.
- Many things in the filesystem library:

  - `path`; that one used to use the default allocator internally, but looks like the newest draft removed that requirement, although it seems to be the intent still.
  - `directory_iterator` and `recursive_directory_iterator`.
  - Some filesystem operations that can construct temporary `path`s .
- `basic_­regex`.
- `thread` and `async`.
- `packaged_task`, allocator support removed in C++17.
- `promise` will need somewhere to put the shared state.
- iostreams.
- Many things are hard-coded to use the default allocator:

  - `error_code::message()`, `error_condition::message()`, `error_category::message()`: these return a `string`, so default allocator only.
  - `bitset`'s stream insertion operator notionally calls `to_string` with the default allocator, though no high-quality implementation would do that in practice.
  - The `to_string` and `to_wstring` free functions return `std::string`/`std::wstring` respectively; no chance to specify your own allocator. Obviously the user-defined literals for `string` (e.g., `"foo"s`) also have no custom allocator support.
  - There are several facets in `<locale>` that have member functions returning either `std::string` or `std::basic_string<charT>`, i.e., using the default allocator (e.g., `numpunct`), or accepting only `basic_string<charT>` (e.g., `money_get`).
  - Various types in `<random>` uses a `vector` with the default allocator.

---

> If anybody knows, what are the reasons for not providing allocator
>   support in `any`, and removing it from `function`?

`any`'s allocator support is [unimplementable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2416). `function`'s allocator support is poorly specified and [plagued with issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r1.html).

Comment: My goodness, what an amazing answer. I figured there might be two or three items I missed, I had no idea the list was this long! Thank you very much for going to the trouble to compile it.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the argument for not supporting allocators in `std::any` and `std::function` actually seems to be the same: It's unimplementable due to the copy constructor which would need to recover the allocator from a type erased context.