# Are there any functions or classes in C++ standard library which are guaranteed to not perform dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, embedded, language-lawyer

There are contexts in which we want our C++ code to not perform dynamic memory allocation ('on the heap'), specifically in some embedded development use cases.

There are standard library classes which can be implemented without dynamic memory allocation: optional, array, tuple, variant to name a few.
The same is true for standard library free functions.

Are there any such classes or functions which are guaranteed by the standard to not allocate memory dynamically? The only functions I could find with such a guarantee are the placement new() functions.

Comment: You've already named 4 *optional, array, tuple, variant*

Comment: @NathanOliver are such “guaranteed”? If so, by which specification?

Comment: @NathanOliver just because they *can* be implemented as such, doesn't mean they *must* be implemented as such.

Comment: @user2864740 cppreference might be a good source of laymen information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional for example

Comment: @Asaf just read the cppreference or, if you do not trust it, the standard - I provided link for `optional`. As a matter of fact, question doesn't make sense to me, as it seems to put horse in front of the carriage. What good is a list of such facilities for you? The question should be asked from other end, i.e. "is such and such facility using dynamic memory"?

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, they are guaranteed.  Which spec? Why the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/) of course.  IMHO this Q is too broad as it requires checking the standard for every type and seeing if it is allowed to dynamically allocate or not.  If you have a particular type you want to use, just check the standard on that type.

Comment: @Asaf A good rule of thumb is if you can't give it an allocator, it won't perform dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Artyer, fails with `std::function`, though

Comment: @Artyer see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056338/standard-library-facilities-which-allocate-but-dont-use-an-allocator

Comment: @SergeyA it seems more useful than the list in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056338/standard-library-facilities-which-allocate-but-dont-use-an-allocator , which received pretty high rating

Comment: The practical part of me says to overload the dynamic allocators to assert and run a coverage test to see if you hit these asserts.  Add your language/library calls to this and see if they fail.

Answer (score 3):

There are very few cases if any where the C++ standard makes any direct guarantee about not using dynamic memory.

On systems where dynamic memory allocation is signal-unsafe, you can be certain that all functions listed as signal-safe are non-allocating. The standard mentions

```
_Exit
abort
forward
initializer_list functions
memcpy
memmove
move
move_if_noexcept
numeric_limits members
quick_exit
signal
type traits
plain lock-free atomic operations
```

If you can assume conformance to another standard, POSIX, then it lists more functions that are [async-signal-safe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03). Some of these functions listed by POSIX are provided by C++ (and C) standards as well (such as `strcat`), and therefore those standard C++ functions will be signal safe on all POSIX systems.

There are a few functions in [new.delete.placement], which are non-allocating by definition.

---

Another question separate from guarantees is, whether a reasonable implementation of a function or a type would not allocate. Many, many things such as `std::tuple` and `std::array` (with non-allocating type arguments naturally) fall into this category.

It would be reasonable that functions which are declared `noexcept`, and do not have any failure path (like setting error code, returning error indicating value, or terminating the process) shouldn't allocate, since allocation may throw.

Conversely, there are functions that in a reasonable implementation do allocate dynamic memory. Obviously those that involve allocators, as well as those listed in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057682/2079303) that you linked. One non-obvious one that often bites people writing signal handlers is missing from the list: It is not at all reasonable to expect `printf` or any of its related functions to not allocate.

Comment: Noexcept doesn't really indicate no allocation in any way. There is a nothrowing version of memory allocation, and exceptions can be caught and swallowed.

Comment: @SergeyA you're right. I demoted that to a reasonable assumption.

Comment: "*You can be certain that all functions listed as signal-safe are non-allocating. This is because memory allocation itself is signal-unsafe.*" You mean memory allocation is permitted to be signal-unsafe. On a platform where memory allocation was signal safe, functions listed as signal safe could allocate memory. So you'd have to know that memory allocation wasn't signal safe on your platform to assume that not being signal safe assures not allocating memory.