# C++ Memory allocation (using allocator) in a type erased context

Tags: c++, memory-management, type-erasure, std, allocator

There are [many classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056338/standard-library-facilities-which-allocate-but-dont-use-an-allocator) in the standard c++ library which potentially allocate memory but do not accept an allocator. Some of them do so because allocating memory in a type-erased context is not possible.

One example is std::any that had a constructor which accepted an Allocator argument at some point of its design but that was discarded because appearently [unimplementable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2416). I did think for a while about this scenario and I wanted to know **what are the exact issues that prevented the its implementation**. **What requirement of the standard cannot be satisfied**?

Let's say we start with a basic implementation of `any`. Allocating memory is trivial:

```
struct any {

    struct type_interface;

    template <typename T>
    struct type_impl;

    type_interface* value;

    any(T&& value, const Allocator& allocator = Allocator()) {
        using actual_allocator_t
            = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::rebind_alloc<type_impl<T>>;
        actual_allocator_t actual_allocator;
        // do allocate
        // do construct
        // assign obtained pointer
    }
};
```

The problem is obviously that we lose the allocator that originally allocated the object `type_impl<T>`. One trick could be to create a method that declare a static variable to store that allocator.

```
template <typename Allocator>
auto& get_allocator(const Allocator& allocator) {
    using actual_allocator_t = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::rebind_alloc<type_impl<T>>;
    // static variable: initialized just on the first call
    static actual_allocator_t actual_allocator(allocator);
    return actual_allocator;
}
// and the constructor is now
any::any(T&& value, const Allocator& allocator = Allocator()) {
    auto actual_allocator = get_allocator(allocator);
    // do allocate
    // do construct
    // assign obtained pointer
}
```

Now we can retrieve the same object to deallocate the previously allocated object. The last problem to solve is the deallocation. An object can't deallocate itself so the same trick can used to wrap the deallocation logic and use it through an interface.

```
// Deallocator interface
struct deallocate_interface{
    virtual void deallocate(void*) {};
};

template <typename Allocator>
struct deallocate_wrapper{
    virtual void deallocate(void* ptr) {
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(
            this->allocator,
            reinterpret_cast<typename Allocator::value_type*>(ptr),
            1u
        );
    }
};
```

And, the same way, store it into a static method:

```
template <typename Allocator>
deallocate_interface& get_deallocator(Allocator& allocator) {
    auto& actual_allocator = get_allocator(allocator);
    // static variable: initialized just on the first call
    static deallocate_wrapper<std::decay_t<decltype(actual_allocator)>> deallocator(actual_allocator);
    return deallocator;
}
```

The only limit I see is that this implementation uses the same allocator for all the objects of the same type, meaning that in case of copy/move the allocator will not be copied/moved. **But isn't this better than no allocator at all**?
I tested the code here (https://github.com/barsan-md/type-erasure-and-allocation) to see if it works as expected.
A possible output is:

```
Begin
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a132, allocating:   0x55ec667e4280
Constructed: 0x55ec667e4280, print: Hello
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a132, allocating:   0x55ec667e42b0
Constructed: 0x55ec667e42b0, print: World
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a140, allocating:   0x55ec667e42e0
Constructed: 0x55ec667e42e0, print: 12345
Destroyed:   0x55ec667e42e0, print: 12345
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a140, deallocating: 0x55ec667e42e0
Destroyed:   0x55ec667e42b0, print: World
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a132, deallocating: 0x55ec667e42b0
Destroyed:   0x55ec667e4280, print: Hello
Allocator: 0x55ec6563a132, deallocating: 0x55ec667e4280
End
```

Comment: One issue with your design is you can't change the allocator for different `any` instances.  If you have set an allocator for `any::type_impl<std::string>` then that is the allocator all `any::type_impl<std::string>`'s will use.

Comment: But allocator offers just allocation and deallocation of memory. What is the issue of mutiple any allocating using the same allocator instance. From an allocator pov must be like std::list allocating multiple nodes.

Comment: Lets say I have one any that I want to use a stack allocator with and then I want to have another one that does dynamic allocation for the same type.  I can't do that in this case.

Comment: In this case the allocators will be different `stack_alloc<T>` and `dynamic_alloc<T>`. They are the same for the same pair of Allocator and T

Comment: Sorry, i see the possible source of confusion. In the example I have shown get_allocator as a stand alone function while it is in reality a member of class any::type_impl, that's how it gets the information about the actual type to be allocated. https://github.com/barsan-md/type-erasure-and-allocation/blob/8d5527ff2b30237660dd67e522720c8eafec2ac2/any.hpp#L68